# Reliable custom shell replacement / wrapper

Tags: linux, shell, signals, fork

I have a situation where I would like to run a small amount of custom logic before the shell executable is launched (/bin/sh or bash) and I'm considering writing a wrapper so that I can move the shell binary to /bin/sh.orig and place my binary at /bin/sh and have it pass through every call to /bin/sh. This seems easy to do in an naive way, but I'd like to understand the best/most reliable way to perform this and ensure proper argument, signal, and I/O operation.

Do I just exec() the new process with args and everything will be fine, or do I need to fork()/wait for signals/exit codes to be handled correctly? I don't want to overthink this, but I'd like my wrapper to correctly operate in the place of the shell executable for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would just make `/bin/sh` a shell script like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh.orig
exec /bin/sh.orig "$@"
```

Test the heck out of it in the context of the whole system; if it works, it works.

The interpreter for the script is `/bin/sh.orig`, and that's what it passes its arguments to.

If `/bin/sh` is Bash, note that Bash changes its behaviors depending on what its name is. Famously, it disables some non-POSIX behaviors when run as `sh`. I suspect that if it's run as `sh.orig`, it will just behave like Bash, with all its extensions.

If this hack is deployed as part of a larger system in which programs not related to your solution depend on a `/bin/sh` interpreter to be POSIX-like, that could break. A possible fix would be to just assume Bash and make `/bin/sh` this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /bin/bash --posix "$@"
```

Note also that if we know that our wrapper is being run by Bash, we can use the `-a` option of `exec` which is not in POSIX. The `-a` option lets `exec` specify `argv[0]` independently of the executable path:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -a /bin/sh /bin/bash "$@"
```

Here, instead of using `--posix`, we execute Bash such that its `argv[0]` is `/bin/sh`, from which it should then behave similarly to as if it were run as `/bin/sh` directly.

I can't seem to get quite the exact behavior. When I enter my fake `sh` interactively, the prompt is `sh-4.4$`  whereas I get a plain `$` prompt when `/bin/sh` is the actual Bash executable rather than a wrapper. `POSIXLY_CORRECT=y` is set either way, yet that is a visible difference.

If your target system's `/bin/sh` isn't Bash, you have to follow some alternate line of reasoning, obviously.

Comment: Totally a "don't overthink this" approach! The shell would certainly have all the plumbing to hand the process handoff, parameters, signals, and pipes.

Perhaps the difference in behavior is interactive login vs non-login session?

Comment: @JoshRivers It's, doh, because I did the experiment in the wrong VM, where /bin/sh is a symlink to dash.